# I can make a function to work for all tools?

Tags: nsis

I want to have something like this :

```
 o  Simulink
   o  Simulink 3D Animation
   o  Simulink Control Design
 o  Stateflow
   o  Stateflow Coder
```

and for example when "o Simulink 3D Animation" is checked, Simulink should automatically be checked and the same thing for Stateflow.

I have the following code for Section :

```
Section /o "Simulink"
    ;SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Simulink$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd

Section "Simulink 3D Animation"
    SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Simulink 3D Animation$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd

Section /o "Simulink Control Design"
    ;SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Simulink Control Design$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd

Section "Stateflow"
    SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Stateflow$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd

Section "Stateflow Coder"
    SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Stateflow Coder$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd
```

And for checked I have the following function :

```
Section /o "Simulink 3D Animation" box_BONUS
    ;SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Simulink 3D Animation$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section  /o "Simulink" box_MAIN
    ;SectionIn RO
    FileWrite $9 "product=Simulink$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Function .OnSelChange
    ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${box_BONUS} 
        MessageBox MB_OK "simple message box"
        !insertmacro SelectSection ${box_MAIN} 
        !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${box_MAIN} ${SF_RO}
    ${Else}
        !insertmacro ClearSectionFlag ${box_MAIN} ${SF_RO}
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

With this code, I don't have the tools grouped, and I don't want to have a function for each tool : one for Simulink, one for Stateflow.... Can I make a function to work for all tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SectionGroup](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/SectionGroup.md) like this:

```
SectionGroup "Simulink"

    Section "Simulink 3D Animation"
        # your code
    SectionEnd

    Section "Simulink Control Design"
        # your code
    SectionEnd

SectionGroupEnd
```

I don't know exactly how your installer is supposed to work. But if, for instance, any sub-section requires some mandatory files, you could add a required section inside your SectionGroup.

```
SectionGroup "Simulink"

    Section -"Required Simulink Stuff"
        # your code
    SectionEnd

    # more Sections

SectionGroupEnd
```

This will always run, once any section inside that SectionGroup has been selected (notice the dash in front of the section name!)

If you're looking for a more advanced setup, why not simply call a function from one of your sub-sections?

```
SectionGroup "Simulink"

    Section "Simulink 3D Animation"
        Call Requirements_3dAnim
    SectionEnd

    # more Sections

SectionGroupEnd

Function Requirements_3dAnim
    # your code
Functions
```

Comment: ok, but here simulink is  just a title. In my case simulink is a tool, and here doesen't exists  Filewrite for this . Or I'm wrong ?

Comment: That's correct, but that's why I suggested two solutions for that: a required section inside the sectiongroup or calling a function from one sub-section.